# How do you make \Rightarrow and \Leftarrow aligned parallel under \begin{proof}?

Tags: proof-package

Here is what I'm trying to type.

```
\begin{proof}

\begin{enumerate}

\item[$\Rightarrow$] bla bla bla

\item[$\Leftarrow$] bla bla bla

\end{enumerate}

\end{proof}
```

But, if I try that, I can't get $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ parallel to make them look nice, if you know what you mean,,,;;
(the $\Rightarrow$ is just on the right of the title "proof", while $\Leftarrow$ is not aligned vertically with $\Rightarrow$ since $\Leftarrow$ is aligned vertically with "proof"...)

How, do I make them parallel to make them look nice?

Comment: My advice is to forget `enumerate`. Just `\begin{proof}($\Rightarrow$)...<empty line>($\Leftarrow$)...\end{proof}`. The arrows already give sufficient visual clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have some thing written directly after the `Proof.` word and before the `enumerate` environment. So, using a `~` will do the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{proof}~
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$\Rightarrow$] bla bla bla
\item[$\Leftarrow$]  bla bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: suggest that you use `\qedhere` before the `\end{enumerate}` to move the "tombstone" up to the last line of the list.  in any event, remove the blank line before `\end{proof}`; otherwise, the "tombstone" could break to a new page if the proof happens to come at the end of a page.